# Complex text extraction using regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of complex strings which are basically ingredients of different products like the following:

```
ingredients = [['Sianliha, Vispautuva kasvirasvasekoite, sorsanrinta, broilerinmaksa, valkuainen, porkkana, palsternakka, purjo, juuripersilja, madeira, suola, E407, valkosipuli, mustapippuri, E300. Vehnäjauho, margariini, suola, kananmunan keltuainen ja liivate.']
['Tomaattimurska 91,5%, ekstra neitsytoliiviöljy 2%, sipuli 2%, riisitärkkelys,basilika 1,3%, suola, sokeri.']
['Eksta neitsyoliiviöljy 38,2%, basilika 34,3%, cashew pähkinäjauhe, Grana Padano juusto 7%(sis. kananmunanjäänteitä), suola, pinjansiemen, perunahiutale, sokeri, happamuudensäätelyaine: maitohappo, antioksidantti: askorbiinihappo.']
['Tomaattimurska 46%, naudan- ja sianliha 24%, tomaattipyree 10,2%, porkkana, sipuli, selleri, ekstra neitsyoliiviöljy 1,8%, suola, vehnäjauho, maitojauhe, sokeri.']
['Tomaattimurska 91,5%, ekstra neitsytoliiviöljy 2%, sipuli 2%, riisitärkkelys,basilika 1,3%, suola, sokeri.']
['viinietikka, rypälemehutiiviste, väriaine E150d']
['valkoviinietikka, rypälemehutiiviste']
['Sian- ja naudanliha, vesi, 1-luokan sulatejuusto (maito, hapate, suola, vesi, maitorasva, happamuudensäätöaine (E509), sulatesuolat (E452, E339, E 331), paakkuuntumisenestoaine (E460)), suola (1,7 %), mausteet (kumina), hydrolysoitu kasviproteiini, kasvirasva, stabilointiaine (E452), säilöntäaine (E250), hapettumisenestoaine (E315,E316), aromit (kumina), mausteuutteet']
['Sian- ja naudan liha, vesi, perunajauho, suola (1,8 %), mausteet (sinapinsiemen), sakkaroosi, hydrolysoitu kasviproteiini, kasvirasva, stabilointiaineet (E450, E452), hapettumisenestoaineet (E315, E316), säilöntäaine (E250), mausteuutteet (mm. selleri, korianteri), aromit (mm.kumina)']
['Sian- ja naudanliha, vesi, suola (1,7 %), mausteet (kumina, mustapippuri, naga morich -chili, valkosipuli), hydrolysoitu kasviproteiini, kasvirasva, glukoosi, stabilointiaine (E450, E452), hapettumisenestoaine (E315,E316), säilöntäaine (E250), mausteuutteet, aromit']
['Sian- ja naudanliha, vesi, suola (1,7 %), mausteet (valkopippuri, muskottipähkinä, korianteri, kardemumma), stabilointiaine (E450), glukoosi, hapettumisenestoaine (E316), säilöntäaine (E250),  aromit']
['Naudanliha, vesi, suola, (1,9 %), glukoosi, stabilointiaineet (E450, E451), hapettumisenestoaine (E316), säilöntäaine (E250), aromit']
['Sianliha, vesi, suola (1,7 %), mausteet (valkopippuri, muskottipähkinä, korianteri, kardemumma, valkosipuli), glukoosi, stabilointiaineet (E450, E451), hapettumisenestoaine (E316), säilöntäaine (E250), aromit']
['Sianliha, vesi, suola (1,7 %), hydrolysoitu kasviproteiini, kasvirasva, mausteet (mm.viherpippuri), glukoosi, stabilointiaine (E450, E451), hapettumisenestoaine (E300, E316), säilöntäaine (E250), mausteuutteet, aromit']
['Sian- ja naudanliha, vesi, suola (1,7 %), mausteet (valkopippuri, muskottipähkinä, korianteri, kardemumma), stabilointiaine (E450), glukoosi, hapettumisenestoaine (E316), säilöntäaine (E250),  aromit']]
```

I need to take out only original words (ingredients) but not the percentages and things contain E with something. Right now I am using the following regex:

```
for i in range (len(ingredients)):
     regex = re.findall(r'\(E\d+\)|\(E \d+\)|([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)', ingredients[i])
```

It works for almost 90% of the cases but if you paste this code on [regex website](https://regex101.com/)
then you'll see there are still few tokens with E are coming in the string which I cannot figure out how to remove. For example, (E450, E451) and E150d (Es without brackets), this kind of text is still unreachable for the regex
How can I do that ? Thanks.

Comment: Your regex101 link is to an empty session...

Comment: What are the rules after all? Can you specify what context you want to discard? Try [`r"\(?\bE\s*\d+\w*\)?\W*|\b([^\W\d]+(?:\s+[^\W\d]+)*)\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/lJgDlq/1) (looks like there is a bug in regex101 - you need to use `re.U` to enable shorthand character classes to be Unicode aware, not `a`, and in Python 3, they are Unicode aware by default).

Comment: (https://regex101.com/r/2JCYmU/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the problem is that I have a huge of all product ingredients which contains these kind of ingredients string so I cannot tell exactly the exact list of things that I want remove. But during data processing I recognized that with the previous I was getting 90% of the results and 7% results were not correct due to the above mentioned problem which I think is somehow solved with your help. There are still 3% small issues :)

Comment: I think this regex works on all the data in the sample input: `(\(?[0-9,]+\s?%\)?)|(\(?(?:E\s?\d[^\s]+)+\)?)`

Comment: You know, it is not a good approach. "Think twice then cut" (in the Russian version, "think seven times" :)). Otherwise, it is a guessing game where you have advantage since we do not see the whole data.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Any good strategies to handle such complex strings ? Actually I have very less knowledge of regex so it will be good if you give few good strategies. In this case you know I can't go through all the data so what should be a good idea ? Thanks

Comment: See Tomalak's answer - maybe identifying what you *don't need* is the best idea here. Then you can remove those substrings, and tokenize the text as usual. Actually, that is what my regex does together with tokenization since in my regex, there is only 1 capturing group and `re.findall` returns the captured texts only.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to take out only original words (ingredients) but not the percentages and things contain E with something.

An expression that seems to do the job well is this:

```
\s*\(?(?:\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*%|E\s*\d+[a-z]?(?:\s*,\s*E\s*?\d+[a-z]?)*)\)?
```

Break-down:

```
\s*                 # leading whitespace
\(?                 # an opening "(", optional
(?:                 # start non-capturing group
  \d+               #   digits
  (?:[.,]\d+)?      #   decimal part, comma or dot separator, optional
  \s*%              #   a percent sign, optionally preceded by space
  |                 #   or...
  E\s*              #   "E" followed by optional whitespace
  \d+[a-z]?         #   multiple digits and an optional character
  (?:               #   start non-capturing group
    \s*,\s*         #     a comma, space optional
    E\s*            #     "E" followed by optional whitespace
    \d+[a-z]?       #     multiple digits and an optional character
  )*                #   end group, repeat if possible
)                   # end group
\)?                 # a closing ")", optional
```

Use it to match the relevant sections and create new lists from the matches.

With small modifications you can remove commas and parentheses from the matches if you don't need them.

Comment: It was really helpful. Thanks